# Default value with primary key sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I've the following class

```
class Comision(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comision'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    key = Column(Integer, default=process())
```

in the column key i've the def `process` and i need to make some operations with the primary key of that table, it is possible to pass it like argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
key = Column(Integer, default=process)
```

or

```
key = Column(Integer, default=lambda:process())
```

Defined as `key = Column(Integer, default=process())`, `process()` is called once only when class `Comision` is defined.

Take a look at `Context-Sensitive Default Functions` in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/defaults.html for more detail.